# Protractor won't take screenshot in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jenkins, webdriver, protractor

I am using the following code to take screenshots (in after each) when a test fails in Protractor:

```
function failScreenshot() {
var fs = require('fs');
var spec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;
var specName = spec.description.split(' ').join('_');

if (spec.results().passed()) {
    return;
} else {
    browser.takeScreenshot().then(
            function(png) {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream('screenshots/' + specName + '.png');
                stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                stream.end();
            });
}
```

}

When I am running the tests locally, the screenshot works just as expected. When running the tests via Jenkins, the tests will stop at the first fail and the screenshot is not created. Also, the folders and paths are correct, I have checked them over and over again. My Jenkins version is 1532.1

Any ideeas on how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further documentation I have found the answer. It was a problem with the path. It seems like NODE JS does not read the path as I thought.

The ./ returns the current directory, except in the require() function. When using require(), it reads ./ to the directory of the file in which it was called (obviously, the mistake was here). __dirname is always the directory of the file in which is used.
The code to be used for my path is the following:

```
__dirname + '/screenshots/' + specName + '.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take the screenshots in jenkins by using the `mocha-proshot` reporter.

It is a npm package which can be downloaded easily and is very easy to setup.